# dplyr: How to prevent transmute from showing 'adding missing grouping variables' message?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am performing a mutation on a dataframe using dplyr's group_by and then transmute. How do I prevent the message 'Adding missing grouping variables: `gender`'?

Reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(gender = rep(c("M", "F"), 10), score = rnorm(10, 5, 2))

df %>% 
  group_by(gender) %>%
  transmute(rank = rank(score), score = score) %>% arrange(score)

# Adding missing grouping variables: `gender`
# A tibble: 20 x 2
# Groups:   gender [2]
   gender  rank
   <fct>  <dbl>
 1 M       9.50
 2 F       1.50
 3 M       7.50
 4 F       3.50
 5 M       3.50
 6 F       5.50
 7 M       1.50
 8 F       7.50
 9 M       5.50
10 F       9.50
11 M       9.50
12 F       1.50
13 M       7.50
14 F       3.50
15 M       3.50
16 F       5.50
17 M       1.50
18 F       7.50
19 M       5.50
20 F       9.50


df %>% 
  group_by(gender) %>%
  transmute(gender, rank = rank(score))

# Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
#   Column `gender` can't be modified because it's a grouping variable
```

This code is part of a larger Shiny app. I know I can prevent the message using 'suppressMessages()', but I am looking for a more specific solution.

Edit: R version 3.3.2
dplyr_0.7.4

Off topic: I have used stackoverflow as a reader for quite some time, but this is my first question. Hope it follows the rules.

Comment: Don't use `transmute`. Use `mutate` and then `ungroup` and then `select` the variables you need.

Comment: >the problem is in using `gender` in the transmute.  You don't need it as `group_by` already gives you that column,  try `df %>% group_by(gender) %>% transmute(rank = rank(score))`

Comment: I don't get the warning either. What version of `dplyr` are you using? I tried `dplyr_0.7.5`. You can check with `sessionInfo()`

Comment: I actually don't get the warning either, it must be in an older version I suppose. But explicitly mutating, ungrouping and selecting will avoid the problem I should think.

Comment: @akrun it is not a warning, just a message

Comment: May be it is because of loading `tidyverse`.  I loaded only the required packages.  Anyway, try wthout using `gender` in the `transmute`, It should work

Comment: @joran thanks for your suggestion! It does the job, indeed, but I was hoping there was a 'cleaner' solution without extra function calls. I added the relevant sessionInfo to the post.

Comment: @Pim Using `dplyr_0.7.5` it is working fine without using `gender` in the `transmute`  You can check the output below

Answer (score 0):

We can use `transmute` after the `group_by`.  Only thing is that the group by variable is not needed in the `transmute` as `group_by` will return that column

```
#R 3.4.4
library(dplyr) # using dplyr_0.7.5 
df %>% 
  group_by(gender) %>%
  transmute(rank = rank(score))
# A tibble: 20 x 2
# Groups:   gender [2]
#   gender  rank
#   <fct>  <dbl>
# 1 M        3.5
# 2 F        1.5
# 3 M        7.5
# 4 F        7.5
# 5 M        9.5
# 6 F        9.5
# 7 M        1.5
# 8 F        5.5
# 9 M        5.5
#10 F        3.5
#11 M        3.5
#12 F        1.5
#13 M        7.5
#14 F        7.5
#15 M        9.5
#16 F        9.5
#17 M        1.5
#18 F        5.5
#19 M        5.5
#20 F        3.5
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I do get the same output, but the message still persists (see edit).

Comment: @Pim May be it is the version difference.  I don't get any message